# default.xml not being read magento 2

Tags: xml, magento, magento2

I'm having real trouble getting my default.xml file to be read in Magento 2.

I've created and applied a custom theme but any changes that I make to the XML file within it don't apply. If I edit the parent theme XML (Luma) it works, so I know the code within it is correct - I must be missing something so simple and I'm hoping that someone can help please.

My file structure is:

```
\app
  \design
    \frontend
      \mycompanyname
        \mythemename
          \layout
            \default.xml
```

Within the XML file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
   See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="top.search" destination="header.panel" />
    <move element="minicart" destination="header.panel" />
</body>
</page>
```

I think I've applied the theme correctly in the back end, is there anything else for me to check?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please do not revert changes that fix problems with your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-reading through the docs, when it was referring to putting the XML file in a folder called 'Magento_Theme' I assumed that it meant the theme folder, ***NOT*** an actual folder called 'Magento Theme' :D

Folder structure is as follows and everything is working:

```
\app
 \design
  \frontend
   \mycompanyname
    \mythemename
     \Magento_Theme
      \layout
       \default.xml
```